# reload UIPickerView on didSelectRow

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I have got a UIPickerView with multiple components/columns. I want the UIPickerView to add another column immediately when a certain row is selected. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add something to the picker view array.Then [pickerview reloadAllComponents];

Answer (score 1):

First, when that certain row is selected (which you can detect via the `[UIPickerViewDelegate: pickerView: didSelectRow: inComponent:]` method)

You'd have to modify your UIPickerViewDataSource to reflect that a new column is added by incrementing the value returned by `[UIPickerViewDataSource numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]`

And then, like Hitman said, `[UIPickerView reloadAllComponents]`.

More details can be found at Apple's documentation for [UIPickerViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView%3adidSelectRow%3ainComponent%3a)  and [UIPickerViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDataSource/numberOfComponentsInPickerView%3a)